# Macbook Pro 17" wont boot from original installation disk

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I was wondering if i could get some help.

I have the 17" Macbook Pro.

My HDD recently failed, so i have gone and got another one and installed it, the new drive is a Corsair Force LX Sata 3 256Gb SSD drive.

I got my original grey installer disks, inserted it, shut down the computer, then booted it back up and held the C button.

It shows up the Apple logo on the grey screen with the spinning thingo under it, and it wont move on from there.

The CD drive seems to be reading and doing stuff, but it hasnt moved from that screen in nearly 40mins.

If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does your SuperDrive work correctly? It is common for them to fail.

I would try creating a bootable USB disk. You will need your original OS X install DVD, and an 8GB or larger USB drive. Follow the instructions on [this page](http://macs.about.com/od/diyguidesprojects/ss/usbflash_3.htm). If your SuperDrive is broken, you can do this from another Mac. You could also download Mavericks from the App Store and create a bootable drive from that.

Comment: The drive is working ok ... I was using it just before the installation of the new drive ... Is there any way i can see if the SSD is working ok? ... Like a bootable diskutility or a bios screen or something like that?

Comment: You could try the verbose mode or single user mode. look [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1533) . What happens if you held the Option Button?

Comment: None of the keyboard shortcuts seem to work ...Its driving me crazy

Comment: How long should it usually take to go from the grey screen to the installer if im running from CD?